# Swagger + Jersey + Guice integration not working

Tags: java, rest, jersey, swagger, guice

Jersey version : 1.19.2.

I have an app which uses guice, camel, vert.x and Jersey for REST services. We bootstrap the services through a GuiceModule and have included Swagger classes there. The thing is that the /swagger/api-docs endpoint returns blank response. Someone who has faced similar issues, please shed some light on this integration.

Comment: Did you try /swagger?

Comment: Yes. Will edit the question to avoid the confusion

Comment: Not /swagger/api-docs, did you try only /swagger?

Comment: Have you tried /your-rest-enpoint/api-docs ?

Comment: Yes I tried <base-url>/api-docs, <base-url>/swagger, <base-url>/swagger/api-docs. Doesn't work